# Cambiar valor de un control de .Net oculto

Tags: javascript, vb.net

Buen día,

Estoy tratando de cambiarle el valor a con textbox que esta oculto en la pagina, lo hago desde una función de JavaScript, pero no me lo cambia. Pero cuando el control lo pongo visible en la pagina si me cambia el valor.

¿Qué puedo hacer para que me cambie el valor con el control oculto en la pagina?

Validación de js:

```js
var r = confirm("Desea cambiar el valor del control?");

            if (!r) {

                $("#txtGuardar_I").val("2")
            }
            else {
                $("#txtGuardar_I").val("1")
            }

Control .Net:
```

```html
<dx:ASPxTextBox ClientIDMode="Static" EnableClientSideAPI="True" runat="server" ID="txtGuardar" Text="0" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="TextPersonalizadoGuardar" BackColor="#F9FFED" ForeColor="#F9FFED" FocusedStyle-BackColor="#F9FFED" Visible="false"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Necesito cambiar el valor del control cuando le di click a un botón y cuando tenga el nuemvo valor el backend haga una operacion con el nuevo valor del control.

Comment: Que tiene que ver .net en esto? podrias mostrar como es que lo estas haciendo?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando trato de cambiar el valor del control por js lo necesito en el backend para que me haga una validación.